# scrollview not showing image first time

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, ios7

background:

- legacy iOS sdk 4.5 app
- tab bar controller with 2 tabs
- `UIScrollView` to display image on first tab

When first tab is displayed at startup, `UIScrollView` is created and image is added as subview. With iOS < 7, image is displayed. With iOS 7, image is not displayed until I click on second tab, then go back to first tab. It doesn't work when I change tab programmatically.

Did someone encounter the same issue? How to solve it...

EDIT:

- scrollview is created programmatically : 
  `scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`
- problem occurs even if I create the frame after clicking a button (so, not in `viewDidLoad` nor `applicationDidFinishLaunching`)
- I set minimum/maximum zoom scale, zoom scale, content offset
- I add image in scrollview :

`UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];`
`[scrollView addSubview:imageView];`

- scrollview is added to the view:

> [self
>   performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(xxxx:)
>   withObject:scrollView waitUntilDone:YES];

where xxxx do: `[self.view addSubview:v];`

Comment: Can you add the code that you're using to create the UIScrollView and add the UIImageView? It would be helpful to see this code, as well as how it is being called (for example by applicationDidFinishLaunching: or whatever).

Comment: Where exactly do you call `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(xxxx:) withObject:scrollView waitUntilDone:YES];`? In what method?

Comment: it is called just after creating the scrollview and adding to it the imageview. Method is button click delegate action for instance.

Comment: Hi @FrancoisB. I'm curious if you found a resolution to this issue.

Comment: Nope. I ended up with a webview :(